# Is there a way to access data declared on an element on that element in Vue js?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I want to know if I can cut down on long text paths to call data if it has already been declared on the element, for instance:

I have this element,

```
<div v-for="client in clients">
<input type="text" :value="client.data.assets.properties.townhouses.twoStory">
</div>
```

and I want to add a class if the data is not present, instead of doing this:

```
<input type="text" :value="client.data.assets.properties.townhouses.twoStory" 
       :class="{ 'class-to-add': !client.data.assets.properties.townhouses.twoStory }">
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
<input type="text" :value="client.data.assets.properties.townhouses.twoStory" 
       :class="{ 'class-to-add': !this.value }">
```

Obviously this does not work, please let me know if you any insights. Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can do that directly, but you can create a computed property called `twoStory` and bind that to both value and class.

Comment: Is this element part of a `v-for` repeater at all?

Comment: Yes a computed property would work but I'm really just trying to cut down on code so creating a computed property for each data I'm using would add too much code. Thanks

Comment: @Phil Yes, sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: What sort of value is `twoStory`? Is it a boolean or a string value?

Comment: @Phil String value

Comment: So the class should be added when it's empty?

Comment: Since the attribute binding expressions are evaluated **before** the element renders, I think you're out of luck.

Comment: Yes please, when it's empty

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought I was dreaming but had to ask.

Comment: Are you consistently using some part of your object chain? e.g. Are you always referring to properties? If so it may be worthwhile to just have one computed property to do something like "return this.client.data.assets.properties". Then you could just do something like prpts.townhouses.twoStory.